# Apache OFBiz new Plugin: missing error message?

Tags: ofbiz

I try to create a new plugin in ofbiz

```
 <request-map uri="main"><security https="true" auth="false"/><response 
     name="success" type="view" value="main"/></request-map>

       <!-- View Mappings -->
   <view-map name="main" type="screen" page="component://xxx/widget
    /xxxScreens.xml#main"/>
```

in ofbiz-componenent.xml:

```
<webapp name="xxx"
 title="xxx"
 server="default-server"
location="webapp/xxx"
 base-permission="OFBTOOLS,XXX"
 mount-point="/xxx"/
```

When I try to call the plugins controller:

```
  https://localhost:8443/xxx/control/main
```

nothing happens:
- empty page (no html structure)
- no error msg, no log entry at all (not in ofbiz.log or error.log)

How can I find out what is going wrong?
How can I get any (further) information?

Comment: Please share what you did to create the plugin in more detail, else it's impossible to guess what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the README.md file which says:

```
Create a new plugin. The following project parameters are passed:

    pluginId: mandatory
    pluginResourceName: optional, default is the Capitalized value of pluginId
    webappName: optional, default is the value of pluginId
    basePermission: optional, default is the UPPERCASE value of pluginId

gradlew createPlugin -PpluginId=myplugin

gradlew createPlugin -PpluginId=myplugin -PpluginResourceName=MyPlugin -PwebappName=mypluginweb -PbasePermission=MYSECURITY

The above commands achieve the following:

    create a new plugin in /specialpurpose/myplugin
    add the plugin to /specialpurpose/component-load.xml
```